# Restrict an APT repo to a single architecture?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I have this warning each time I run `apt update` on `Ubuntu 20.04.2` :

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I know that I need the `i386` arch for certain packages, but I would like to know if it is possible to prevent `apt` to scan the `i386` release of the `miktex`

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found (on the `docker` official linux [install guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)) that adding `[arch=*whatever arch needed*]` between `deb` and the `URL` is doing exactly that